# Ubuntu freezes booting up after hibernation

Tags: 10.10, hibernate, thinkpad, lenovo

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad Edge 13 ([Intel model](http://www.zdnet.com/reviews/product/laptops/lenovo-thinkpad-edge-13-inch/33939705))

I've gotten everything to work under Ubuntu except for hibernation. The system hibernates normally but when Ubuntu tries to boot from the hibernation file, it freezes.

I tried with the 2.6.35 kernel and the newer 2.6.36 (which solved my eating-battery problems), but this issue persists.

How could I troubleshoot this issue?

EDIT:

- My Ubuntu install is in a separate
  partition alongside Windows 7.

  I've tried a BIOS update today, and
  the problem still persists.

  My swap partition is bigger than my installed Ram (2,3GB vs 2,0 GB)

Suspend as a sleep method works, but I really need my hibernation option.

Comment: can you provide us more information on how your ubuntu is installed; wubi? another work around is using standby

Comment: Is it really a freeze or does it only take unusually long like 10 min or so (I've seen that before)?

Comment: @dustyprogrammer I'll add the info in my question

Comment: @Takkat it's a real freeze, the only way to recover the computer is my rebooting

Comment: @Takkat Same problem for me in my dell laptop but with ubuntu 10.04.... Suspending is fine but as soon as you hibernate it just freezes up for 10- 15 min... do you know the answer for that ?

Comment: I'd recommend you open a new question about this issue giving detailed info about your hardwar.

Comment: Check if your swap partition is equal or bigger than your ram.
Hibernation copies ram contents into hdd so if swap partition can't contain your ram you could face problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. Turns out it was the package

> uswsusp

which replaces the default hibernate and sleep methods, the one that was causing the freezing. I uninstalled it and reverted to the default Ubuntu hibernate and it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

I would try a BIOS update as there seems to be some issues with power in the past. I have known BIOS updates to solve these issues. Try [here](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/MIGR-74279.html#notes).

Comment: Thank you, both for the info and the link; but BIOS update didn't solve the problem unfortunately =(, still looking for the solution

Answer (score 1):

There are often clues in /var/log/messages. Look for what the kernel said around the time of the crash or hibernate attempt.

Comment: I didn't know this, will try today =)

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following

1. Update the bios
2. Install the latest kernel
3. Install the proprietary graphics driver